# Filtering unique value in new column Excel

Tags: excel

I have this table on excel

```
    Car_Engine

    Type1EngineA
    Type1EngineB
    Type1EngineC
    Type1EngineD
    Type1EngineE
    Type2EngineO
    Type1EngineF
    Type2EngineB
    Type2EngineC
    Type3EngineA
    Type4EngineA
    TypeTEngineB
```

I want to generate the “Car type” column this way

```
Car_Type    Car_Engine

Type1   Type1EngineA
Type1   Type1EngineB
Type1   Type1EngineC
Type1   Type1EngineD
Type1   Type1EngineE
Type2   Type2EngineO
TypeCC  TypeCCEngineF
Type2   Type2EngineB
Type2   Type2EngineC
Type3   Type3EngineA
Type4   Type4EngineA
TypeT   TypeTEngineB
```

What’s in your opinion the best way to do that? The EngineA, EngineB etc.. are replaced with real engines names, same for types!

Comment: Functions like `Right`, `Left`, `Len`, `Find` can help you strip out strings into a new column. In your case, this may be difficult unless there is a *pattern* to your data e.g. `car_type` is always n characters in length, `engine` always starts with `_` etc. Showing actual data would help here.

Answer (score -1):

assuming car_engine column is A:

car_type column:  =LEFT(A3;SEARCH("Engine";A3;1)-1)

(I'm wondering where is "CC" coming from)

Comment: can you see "TypeCCEngineF" on first table?  I can't

Comment: so the question is "How to divide a word into two words without knowing where to cut", isn't it ?